# What is the best way to create a Ecommerce website using PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, codeigniter, magento

Maybe the the question have been asked so many times, and many may votes this down, But i am really confused and i think its the best place to ask the professionals to resolve my problem.

I know we can use wordpress, magentto, open cart or others to create a E-Commerce site, but I want to create a ecommerce site using codeigniter.. Kindly guide me is it better to create a eCommerce site using codeigniter or the above mentioned tools are better. What is being used in the Industry?

I have never created a eCommerce site so far, I have created eCommerce sites using wordpress themes, but i haven't created a theme yet.

I am going to start learning How to create eCommerce site, Kindly guide me where to start, which tool i need to learn first? Theme Developement? Codeigniter Ecommerce ? Magentto? or any other? Which tool will be more beneficial for me in future, and will help me in getting a better job.

Many Thanks

Comment: I think you should go with Magento OR Woo Commerce plugin (in Wordpress) for the E-Commerce site, rather than making site from scratch.

Comment: What is being used in the industry? Magentto Go or Magentto?

Comment: I am on Magento website and it looks like it is not free?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you go with Magento community edition it is free.

You will get lot of benefit from Magento , under Magento admin section you have lot of configuration to Manage your site easily.

You can also get the extension for customization from Magento connect for the addition functionality enhancements.

With Magento you will also get some payment methods like Paypal, Cash on delivery, pay by check and pay by credit card.

Magento is more secure compared to Wordpress

Building an ecommerce site from scratch will be painful task for you.

Comment: Thanks, Is it secure? I read some where wordpress is not much secure for creating eCommerce site, so is Magento is secure for creating a eCommerce site? and Would it create problem for me in getting job if i only Know Magento and not the core of eCommerce sites? I think in Magento i don't need to learn Payment API's etc..

Comment: @user3480644 Magento is more secure compared to Wordpress.

Comment: I am start learning Magento. I have downloaded the LevelupTuts Magento Community Tutorial. What Level of PHP is required to learn it? I have 1 year experienced of PHP, would that experience will help me in learning Magento or is it like wordpress, Click and things will happen.

Comment: Magento also contains admin side like word press where you can add products, payment gateway infos, etc.

Comment: @user3480644 you should have basic understanding of MVC

Comment: can i create themes and plugins in Magento using PHP?